# Opening website projects created via WebMatrix 3 in Visual Studio Community 2013

Tags: visual-studio, web, iis-express, webmatrix-3

I'm going through some ASP.NET tutorials on the Getting Started section of the ASP.NET website at Microsoft. I initially used WebMatrix 3 but decided to switch to the recently released Visual Studio Community 2013 (VSC from here on). Running VSC I saw I could open websites via the Local IIS project load option and the WebMatrix-created sites were listed.

However, when it came to saving the project, VSC first asks me where to save the .sln project files. I chose to save it in the same folder created when I was using WebMatrix 3. It seemed to save with no complaints. When I try to right-click on a Razor file to launch it in a browser I get this error on the page:

**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

**Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.**

**Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

A summary on what to watch out for when opening website projects not created in VSC via VSCs **Local IIS load** option would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I also tried clicking on the Launch Visual Studio button in the WebMatrix toolbar but this first throws up the following dialog:

[image]

and does not seem to load the website project at all, just firing up VS. I'm mainly interested in having access to the WebMatrix templates, which do not seem to be available for installing via Visual Studios Online Extensions menu. Also, I have Visual Studio running with elevated permissions.

Comment: It seems setting WebMatrix to run with Administrator privileges has solved the issue of WebMatrix not loading the project when clicking on the Launch Visual Studio button.

Answer (score 0):

It seems setting WebMatrix to run with Administrator privileges has solved all my issues. Now continuing with the ASP.NET tutorial using Visual Studio IDE with no problems so far.

Comment: Had issues when the tutorial mentioned installing **ASP.NET Web Helper Library** via Nuget. This package only exists in the WebMatrix Nuget sources and is not available if you search by that name in the VS2013 Nuget sources. The VS2013 name for this package is **Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers**  I had to use VS2013 Nuget console and issue the following commands:  **update-package**  and then **install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers**